# VBA Copying the last line of info and pasting and inserting a new row in a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the last line of information in column D from the workbook "kitting" and place it on the new last row of workbook "Production Schedule 2021" in column Q. I keep on getting "invalid use of property" error, but I do not know what is wrong.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()


Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet

Set wkb = Excel.Workbooks("Kitting.xlsm")
Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("Kitting Priority")

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
 
 Windows("Production Schedule 2021.xlsm").Activate
  'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
  Set wsCopy = wks
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("Production Schedule.xlsm").Worksheets("Daily")
    
  '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    
  
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "q").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row


  wsCopy.Rows(lCopyLastRow).Copy
    wsDest.Rows(lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial
    
  
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like an extra period in `WS.Copy.Activate` but that line is probably not needed anyway.

Comment: Change `Range` to `Rows` in the last two lines.

Comment: You really need `Option Explicit` at the top of the module to flag undeclared variables.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks, for the suggestions. Now it returns invalid inside procedure?

Comment: At the very very top of the module above everything else.

Comment: Thank you all for the help.